# Adding MathML export rules

Tags: export, customization, xml

Prior to v12.1 `Row` was not handled well by MathML export:

> [image]

Now it is ok:

`ExportString[Row[{1}], "MathML"]`

```html
 <math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <semantics>
  <mrow>
   <mn>1</mn>
  </mrow>
  <annotation encoding='Mathematica'>TemplateBox[List[&quot;1&quot;], &quot;RowDefault&quot;]</annotation>
 </semantics>
</math>
```

But I need to fix that issue for projects where earlier versions are used.

Is there a general way to add conversion rules or at least a fix for `Row`?

Comment: Looks like the relevant function is ``System`Convert`MathMLDump`BoxesToSMML``- if you want to look at it with ``GeneralUtiities`PrintDefinitions``, you'll probably need to remove the limit on the number of definitions with ``DownValues@GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions = 
  DownValues@GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions /. 256 -> \[Infinity];`` or similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding my comment into a concrete answer: Using `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` to look at the functions responsible for the `"MathML"` export<sup>1</sup>, it looks like the core function is `` System`Convert`MathMLDump`BoxesToSMML ``:

```
(* remove limit on number of definitions *)
DownValues@GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions =  
  DownValues@GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions /. 256 -> Infinity;
(* print definitions of the function *)
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@System`Convert`MathMLDump`BoxesToSMML;
```

The following sections outline how to fix the following three issues:

1. `ExportString[Row[{1}], "MathML"]` doesn't work before version 12.1 due to missing transformation rules for `TemplateBox`
2. `ExportString[ToBoxes[a==b],"MathML"]` exports the `==` as `&#10869;`, since the character mappings are not set properly
3. `ExportString[a==b,"MathML"]` exports the `==` as `&#63449;` (even with the fix for 2.), since there is no mapping for `\[LongEqual]` (the `TraditionalForm` version of `==`) in the default mappings

## Adding rules for box structures

In version 12.1, there are two definitions that seem to be responsible for the conversion of `TemplateBox` expressions (which is what `Row` is converted to by `ToBoxes`) - extracting them and adding them in e.g. 11.3 yields the following result:

```
Begin["System`Convert`MathMLDump`"];

BoxesToSMML[whole : TemplateBox[{__}, _, ___]] /; ! alreadyWrapped := Block[
   {alreadyWrapped = True},
   XMLElement[
    "semantics",
    {},
    {
     BoxesToSMML@BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes@whole,
     BoxesToSMML@annotationWrapper@TagBox[whole, "MathMLMathematicaTag"]
     }
    ]
   ];

BoxesToSMML[whole : TemplateBox[{___}, _, ___]] := 
  BoxesToSMML@BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes@whole;

End[];

ExportString[Row[{1}], "MathML"]
```

```html
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <semantics>
  <mrow>
   <mn>1</mn>
  </mrow>
  <annotation encoding='Mathematica'>TemplateBox[List[&quot;1&quot;], &quot;RowDefault&quot;]</annotation>
 </semantics>
</math>
```

The definitions effectively use `` BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes `` to convert arbitrary `TemplateBox` expressions to their resulting boxes, so this should work for (almost) all `TemplateBox` expressions, not just `Row`.

## Specifying the mappings for special characters

It looks like special characters are not exported properly, even though there is a list for special character mappings for MathML<sup>2</sup>:

```
ExportString[ToBoxes[a == b], "MathML"]
```

```html
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <mrow>
  <mi>a</mi>
  <mo>&#10869;</mo>
  <mi>b</mi>
 </mrow>
</math>
```

The list of mappings (which is not used by default for some reason) does include a case for `\[Equal]`:

```
System`Convert`MLStringDataDump`$UnicodeToMathML2Entities
(* {..., "\[Equal]" -> "&Equal;" ,...} *)
```

Luckily, the necessary option for `` System`Convert`XMLDump`WriteSymbolicXML `` is passed through from the top-level, so we can just add it:

```
ExportString[ToBoxes[a == b], "MathML", "Entities" -> "MathML"]
```

```html
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <mrow>
  <mi>a</mi>
  <mo>&Equal;</mo>
  <mi>b</mi>
 </mrow>
</math>
```

Possible values for `"Entities"` can be found in the definition of `` System`Convert`XMLDump`addEntitiesToExportFunction ``:

```
"HTML"
"MathML"
"MathML1"
"MathML2"
_String->_String
_String:>_String (* equivalent to the previous, the delayed evaluation doesn't work *)
{...} (* list of allowed values *)
```

## Adding custom rules to the character mappings

Unfortunately, the above fix is not enough for `a==b`:

ExportString[a == b, "MathML", "Entities" -> "MathML"]

```html
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <mrow>
  <mi>a</mi>
  <mo>&#63449;</mo>
  <mi>b</mi>
 </mrow>
</math>
```

The issue is that by default, the boxes are created using `MakeBoxes[expr,TraditionalForm]`, which formats `==` as `\[LongEqual]`, which is not in the list of mappings. Since `` System`Convert`XMLDump`determineEntityExportFunction `` memoizes the conversion functions and since the first call to the MathML exporter resets the list of mappings, we have to be a bit creative to get the mapping in there:

```
(* needs fresh kernel session *)
(* load the MathML exporter, but without setting "Entities" to avoid memoization *)
ExportString[a == b, "MathML", "Entities" -> {"x" -> "x"}];

(* add custom character mappings *)
System`Convert`MLStringDataDump`$UnicodeToMathML2Entities = 
  System`Convert`MLStringDataDump`$UnicodeToMathML2Entities~Union~{
    "\[LongEqual]" -> "&Equal;"
};

(* now it works *)
ExportString[a == b, "MathML", "Entities" -> "MathML"]
```

```html
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <mrow>
  <mi>a</mi>
  <mo>&Equal;</mo>
  <mi>b</mi>
 </mrow>
</math>
```

<sup>1</sup>For the curious: The call tree essentially looks like this:

- `ExportString` to `Export` (which is used to export to a temporary file):

  - `ExportString`
  - `` System`ConvertersDump`ExportStringTest ``
  - `Export`
- `Export` to `` System`ConvertersDump`export `` (this is the function which calls the correct function for a given format)

  - `Export`
  - `` System`ConvertersDump`ExportTest ``
  - `` System`ConvertersDump`ExportInternal ``
  - `` System`ConvertersDump`export ``
- `` System`ConvertersDump`export `` to `` System`Convert`MathMLDump`BoxesToSMML `` (which is the function we're interested in)

  - `` System`ConvertersDump`export ``
  - `` System`Convert`MathMLDump`mathMLExport ``
  - `` System`Convert`MathMLDump`exportMathMLAux ``
  - `` System`Convert`MathMLDump`exportFunction ``
  - `` XML`MathML`BoxesToSymbolicMathML ``
  - `` System`Convert`MathMLDump`includeFormat ``
  - `` System`Convert`MathMLDump`BoxesToSMML ``

<sup>2</sup>The relevant part of the call tree here is (starting from above):

- see above until `` System`Convert`MathMLDump`exportMathMLAux ``
- `` System`Convert`XMLDump`WriteSymbolicXML ``
- `` System`Convert`XMLDump`determineEntityExportFunction ``
- `` System`Convert`XMLDump`addEntitiesToExportFunction ``

Comment: Thanks for your time! Can you add a piece for the part where XMLElements are converted to the final string? I think I need to adjust that part to solve and issue I have with `==` being exported as a non standard unicode character: `ExportString[a == b, "MathML"]`

Comment: @Kuba It took some trying, but I found an ok-ish workaround (added to the post). Instead of modifying the `"MathML"`mappings as in the third part, you could probably also specify them manually as `"Entities"->{"MathML", "\[LongEqual]"->...}` (not tested though), but I felt it's cleaner to modify the mappings themselves instead to include the missing rules